# Is there a way to check for Fragment's onResume inside Recycler View Adapter class?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, fragment, android-adapter

I have a `recyclerViewAdapter` class where I want some logic to be performed when the `onResume` method is called inside my Fragment holding the adapter. This means that once a user presses the back button to return to the fragment, an operation would take place inside the adapter.

Is there a way to this?

Comment: does this reply solve your problem? https://stackoverflow.com/a/58300492/7360848. If so, you might accept it. If not, comment your issues.

Comment: it does. thanks for your assistance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There can be a couple of solutions. You can use the observer pattern here.

1. Define a Listener and implement it on the `RecyclerView` Adapter class.
2. Make a reference of the Listener from the RecyclerView Adapter Object inside Fragment.
3. Inside onResume of Fragment, call the listener's method.

For details, check [this](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Creating-Custom-Listeners) tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

You an make a method in recyclerViewAdapter and call it in onResume callback of containing fragment.